# настройка Nginx Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Что нужно дописать в конфигах чтобы выполнялись скрипты из директорий.На данный момент только из www запускаются,если указываю еще и директорию выдает 404.

Содержимеое `default` файла

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали как nginx'у работать с php файлами. Для этого вам нужен php-fastcgi:

`location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/example.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }`

Так же файл default не стоит использовать как файл хоста. Советую почитать как делать хосты для Nginx. [Например тут.](http://rav.pw/nginx-virtual-hosts/)

[Пример настройки Nginx + FastCGI для Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/install-and-configure-nginx-and-php-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-16-04)